# Performance: Multidimensional Lists vs Flat List

Tags: python, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

I am using very large lists of lists in python to do some maths with, but then it started lagging quite a bit (~20 seconds). I then started comparing multidimensional and flat lists.

**Code**

```
from timeit import timeit
from sys import getsizeof
print("Literals:")
print("Flat list: {} seconds".format(timeit("[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]")))
print("Mult list: {} seconds".format(
    timeit("[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]")))
a = list(range(100))
b = [list(range(i * 10, i * 10 + 10)) for i in range(10)]
print("\nSizes:")
print("Flat list: {} bytes".format(getsizeof(a)))
print("Mult list: {} bytes".format(getsizeof(b)))
print("\nAppending:")
print("Flat list: {} seconds".format(
    timeit("a.extend((1, 2, 3))", "a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]")))
print("Mult list: {} seconds".format(
    timeit("b.append([1, 2, 3])", "b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]")))
```

**Output**

```
Literals:
Flat list: 0.17474557721948392 seconds
Mult list: 0.39777811142990527 seconds

Sizes:
Flat list: 508 bytes
Mult list: 100 bytes

Appending:
Flat list: 0.11419465630051207 seconds
Mult list: 0.17854960247173668 seconds
```

This tells me that multidimensional lists take longer to change but take less memory, but I can't be for certain, as many of the timings require different methods that may take more or less time. Which list type is more efficient, and in which circumstances?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `numpy`?  If you're doing math on large lists, the performance differences between using vector ops on numpy arrays and using iteration on Python lists will dwarf most anything else you'd think of doing.

Comment: I'm actually fairly new to python programming, and had never heard of it. Thanks for suggesting it! I took a look, and it seems to be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getsizeof` only returns the memory size of the outmost list. Also, the time it takes to create lists is negligible, compared to calculations on the lists. For numeric performance with large sets of numbers use numpy.